# How to get access to usb device file on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, usb, avrdude

I need to avoid using Android USB API and just get access to USB device file (like `/dev/bus/usb/002/002` file) from my android app. Is there any opportunity to do it **without rooting**?

Now i'm getting **permission error** (from child process):

```
W/System.err( 9368): avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/bus/usb/002/002": Permission denied
W/System.err( 9368): ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No access to file directly. Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getFileDescriptor() instead